# Synthetic proof of curvature formula

Tags: euclidean-geometry

The radius of curvature of a curve $\gamma:I \to \mathbf{R}$ parametric by arc length is $||\ddot \gamma||^{-1}$.

I want to demonstrate this using synthetic geometry.

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be three noncolinear points with $AB = BC = 1$ and let $O$ be the center of the circle passing through $A$, $B$ and $C$. And let $D$ be a point such that $ABCD$ is a parallelogram. This is illustrated below:

[image]

I want to show that

$$BD \times BO = 1.$$

This is simple enough to do with trigonometry. Bur is there a more elegant way to show this?

Comment: Note that riangles BAD and BOA are similar.

Comment: Thanks karvens! That was *exactly* what I was looking for!